# PHP Mailchimp v3

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

i am using Mailchimp for the first time, i want to send email, using mailchimp api integrated with php, with following code below i can only add members to the list, what i want is that when some ones fill the form it should get a reply email,

here is the code

```
<?php

    $list_id = 'hidden';
    $api_key = 'hidden';


    $email = 'abdul12@gmail.com';


    $data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);

    $url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed', 
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $status_code;


    echo "<pre>" ;
     print_r($result) ;

     echo   "</pre>";

?>
```

again, i want to send emails to the one who has filled the form, i can only add list members, right now code is working fine when it comes to adding members to list only

Comment: Didn't read the question properly but you may use the simple api wrapper for mailchimp: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api

Comment: i have used that api as well, it only add members to the list

Answer (score 0):

You [can’t send transaction emails using Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-transactional-email/). You could use an automation in Mailchimp to send a welcome email, if that’s what you’re trying to do.

You can pay to use [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com), Mailchimp’s transaction email product. Or consider using SendGrid, Postmark, a few others.

Comment: actually, i will do cron jobs, i will be sending emails to all users from my database,we already had a system setup using php mail functions, but to get template of what we want we want to migrate to the mailchimp, but what i have come to know it can not send emails like that, it only send emails to the subscribers on the list

Comment: I would really recommend getting somebody else to send your emails for you. Good luck.

Comment: we can't send email using php code with mailchamp api?

Comment: “You can’t send transaction emails using Mailchimp”, regardless of what language you’re using.